# TPS9264x Synchronous Buck Controllers for Precision Dimming LED Drivers

Tags: buck, control, led-driver, texas-instruments

I have some questions about TI's TPS92641.
Please see below:

1.) Does anybody know the principle of Chopper OTA? there are no too much information in the datasheet.
[image]

2.) What's Quasi-hysteretic control? I google it but I couldn't find paper told this control theory.

Comment: Do you know what hysteretic control is? Do you know what quasi means?

Comment: @Andyaka I know hysteretic control. but I don't know quasi

Comment: Hysteretic control implies a simple on/off techniques for activating the upper-side switch in a buck converter based on the output ripple. Add a constant-on- or constant-off-time generator and it becomes a quasi-hysteretic mode of operation. This is a quasi-comment : )

Comment: @VerbalKint  if it's a hickup comment , drink water

Comment: It's proprietary PWM that allows 20k levels of PWM but sync'd choppers allow offset free sampling and restoring DC levels by switching the complementary differential voltage and thus is AC coupled gain

Comment: @VerbalKint 
Do they mention on your book?

Comment: My book describes constant on- and off-time hysteretic converters small-signal models, yes.

Answer (score 2):

For the offset compensation, Ccomp is integrating the current out of the gm amp.  There's a clock and switches on the input and output of the amplifier that switch the polarity of BOTH the input and output, presumably with a 50% duty cycle.

Therefore, any offset in the amplifier increases the voltage on Ccomp during 1/2 clock cycle and decreases it during the other, averaging to zero.

The buck is a constant on-time converter where the on time is set based on Vin and Vout.  At the start of each switching cycle the buck switch turns on for a fixed period of time.  If the output voltage rises above the regulation point the switch stays off until it falls below the setpoint.  Then the cycle repeats.  This has the advantage that during transients the switching frequency can increase for very good transient response.  In steady-state with fixed input voltage the switching frequency will be close to constant.

Comment: Hi John, 
Do you have related figure could share with me, it is hard to understand for me.